# Get the table index with a certain name in a powerpoint using openxml

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I have a slide which may have multiple blank tables with just the table headers,
i need to populate table data, which i am able to do by using table id(currently i am hardcoding the table index). but what i am struggling with is, i need to identify table with its caption or something, and get its index, but PPT does not support caption for table, so what is the alternative to this approach.

code to write table row

```
 var tables = from shape in slidePart.Slide.Descendants<D.Table>()
                         select shape;
            tables.ToList()[tableIndex].Append(tableRow);
```

with below code i can find table properties

```
if (slidePart.Slide != null)
        {
            var tables = from shape in slidePart.Slide.Descendants<D.Table>()
                         select shape;
            foreach(D.Table table in tables)
            {
                IEnumerable<TableProperties> tableProperties = table.Descendants<TableProperties>();//.Where(tp => tp. != null);
                foreach (TableProperties tProp in tableProperties)
                {
                    //can i get index of table here?
                }
                //table.Where(r=>r.ChildElements.)
            }
        }
```